# PHP difference between Single-byte strings and Multi-byte strings

Tags: php

For dummies, in PHP what is the difference between single-byte strings and multi-byte strings and in which situations should we consider one or another?

> For single-byte strings (e.g. US-ASCII, ISO 8859 family, etc.) use
>   substr and for multi-byte strings (e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.) use
>   mb_substr:
>
> ```
> // singlebyte strings
> $result = substr($myStr, 0, 5);
> // multibyte strings
> $result = mb_substr($myStr, 0, 5);
> ```

For instance, if I plan to develop something to be used in china, do I need to adopt any special measures because of their special characters ? Isnt' Utf-8 encoding good enough?

Comment: PHP doesnt understand UTF-8, you need to tell it that your string is UTF-8 (as chinese characters are), then use 'mb_x' functions to work on them. Notice that 'mb_x' funcs are working on x-bytes per 1 character, while non 'mb_x' are working on 1-byte per character.

Comment: damn! thanks but thats a complex explanation man

Comment: You can always use mb_ functions, regardless the characterset, and be on the safe site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `strlen` (Single bytes) returned full count bytes, and function `mb_strlen` returned count characters!

The char can be have a more then 1 byte (UTF-8 for example).

For you example:

```
$myStr = '៘៥឴ឨឆ';
$result = substr($myStr, 0, 5);
$result = mb_substr($myStr, 0, 5, mb_detect_encoding($myStr));
```

Function `substr` in this example return invalid value, because chars have more the one byte, but function mb_substr returned correct data.